# How to find all feed directories where a particular site has submitted his feed

Tags: rss

I am looking for a list of working sites which accepts feeds, then I struck with an idea that I can find those places by following other sites of my niche which would have already submitted their feed?  So is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this. But if you Google "rss feed directory" and "rss directory" you should find all the most popular quite easily.